# How to get closing price of most right-hand visible bar on a tradingview chart?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to get the closing price of the most right-hand last bar visible on a tradingview chart with pine-script.

I am using pine-script v5

Answer (score 1):

`chart.right_visible_bar_time` variable will return the time of the rightmost bar currently visible on the chart.

`time` variable will return the current bar time.

Comparing them will return `true` only on the rightmost visible bar. You can have things done when this condition is true (like assigning the `close` price to your own variable) but keep in mind it will reset on each bar unless you use the `var` keyword.

```
var float rightmostClosePrice = na

if time == chart.right_visible_bar_time
    rightmostClosePrice := close

t = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
table.cell(table_id = t, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Close is " + str.tostring(rightmostClosePrice))
```